# Select country and language in HTML

Tags: html, web-applications, internationalization

I'm currently building my site, I want to know how to do this...

Basically, when your press that country, it ask for the language available to you, and then it will redirect to that language page.

How could I do that? like airlines website, you choose a country, then language and then it directs to that language page?

Comment: How is your HTML generated? Statically or dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

This will usually require some server-side processing like PHP.  When the user selects a language from the form, the language choice is stored in the session and recalled on each page load.

Then you would typically have [internationalization strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) in your web application.  The chosen language is used to select the correct i18n strings from the index.

Using plain html only, with no server-side processing, the language selection form would simply (possibly via javascript) redirect to a document root for the language.  This requires you to have a *full* site coded in each language.

```
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com/en/
http://www.example.com/de/
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in many different ways.

Here's a simple way to do it:

Have a bunch of links, each a different country. When you click on one, such as:

```
<a href="#" onclick="getLanguages('france')" >France</a>
```

This will call the JavaScript Function 'getLanguages()' shown here:

```
<script>
function getLanguages(country){
    if(country == "france"){
        document.getElementById("languages").innerHTML = "<a href='/french.html'>French</a><a href='/english.html'>English</a><a href='/german.html'>German</a>";
    }else if(country == "china"){
        document.getElementById("languages").innerHTML = "<a href='/chinese.html'>Chinese</a><a href='/english.html'>English</a><a href='/japanese.html'>Japanese</a>";
    }
}
</script>
```

Obviously you'd have many more if statements for each country represented. This will basically modify an element with the ID of "languages":

```
<div id="languages"></div>
```

to include the possible languages for that country. Then when a user clicks on one of those links, it will take them to the correct page!

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: This is a terrible idea for a real website, because you're relying on JavaScript to put content on the page.  What if the user has blocked JavaScript? How will your multilingual content be indexed by search bots? You could probably get it to work (poorly) by using hash bangs and modifying your URL, but that's more work than it's worth. Stick with server-side processing and you'll be much happier.

Comment: This is just one way to do it. Sure it may not be a good idea, but from what sandy was saying, this seems to be the method that s/he found on the 'airlines' site.